# Unable to produce a newline for useful output with ansible shell output going to lineinfile module

Tags: linux, bash, automation, ansible

Tasks below,  When I run the find command on the shell, I get output expected.  When I debug it after registering the variable, I also get the output one per line.

When I run these tasks I wrote, I get a mess of output that just won't work no matter where I put the newline.

```
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: find / -xdev \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f | awk '{print "-a always,exit -F path=" $1 " -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged" }'
      register: ps

    - name: Put them into the rules file
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: "/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules"
        insertafter: EOF
        line: "{{ ps.stdout_lines }}"
```

I've tried adding a newline to the end of the find both inside and outside of the quote but it's getting mashed up somehow.

What is a fix?   and why is this not working as is ?

Comment: It would be helpful to include (at least a representative snippet of) the output out got and the output you expected.  Have you tried quoting the value of cmd yet?  Probably with double quote, and you may need to escape the embedded double quotes.

Comment: So, I've fixed my initial problem. I changed ```stdout_lines``` to ```stdout``` .  
I suppose I don't understand those,  My issue now is that ansible is duplicating the content on each run.

Comment: ```-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/fusermount -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/su -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chage -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/gpasswd -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/newgrp -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged
```

Comment: You might have better luck with using blockinfile.  It will insert a set of (customizable) markers.  lineinfile probably can't tell if it did or did not already insert your content.

Comment: Next time just update the question with additional data (instead of a comment).

Comment: Suggest you also sort the output from find (see https://serverfault.com/questions/181787/find-command-default-sorting-order) just so ansible doesn't rewrite the file on every run.

Comment: @AllanWind  I am just seeing your comments now, all of them are 100% accurate.  I will absolutely sort them with find.

Comment: `find ... | sort | ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stdout`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout) is raw output while `stdout_lines` is an array that `"{ ... }"` converts to a string (without newlines).

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: find privileged files
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: find / -xdev \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f | awk '{print "-a always,exit -F path=" $1 " -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged" }'
      register: ps

    - name: Put them into the rules file
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        path: "/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules"
        insertafter: EOF
        state: present
        block: "{{ ps.stdout }}"
```

Thank you to everyone who replied,  I figured out the issue.  Posted modified code above.